# session_id gotten from my python playwright script different from what i get in the browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, playwright-python

so im trying to scrape an api. I found the url and i can make a post request to retrieve the data by using the session_id i got from opening the site manually. This is the code:

```
import requests
import json
from cred import session_id, origin, referer, website, api_url


cookies = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.1463518167.1654244215',
    'tz': 'Africa/Lagos',
    'frontend_lang': 'en_US',
    'session_id': session_id,
    'cids': '1',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.402550658.1654629813',
}

headers = {
    'authority': website,
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8',
    'origin': origin,
    'referer': referer,
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/102.0.1245.33',
}

json_data = {
    'id': 22,
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
    'method': 'call',
    'params': {
        'args': [],
        'model': 'report.pos.order',
        'method': 'read_group',
        'kwargs': {
            'context': {
                'pivot_column_groupby': [
                    'date:month',
                ],
                'pivot_row_groupby': [
                    'product_id',
                ],
            },
            'domain': [],
            'fields': [
                'product_qty:sum',
                'average_price:avg',
                'price_total:sum',
            ],
            'groupby': [
                'product_id',
            ],
            'lazy': False,
        },
    },
}

response = requests.post(api_url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
print(response.json())
```

However, when i attempt to obtain session_id prgrammatically, with requests, im told the session has expired.

```
import requests
import json
from cred import origin, referer, website, login, password, api_url
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


headers = {
    'authority': website,
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8',
    'origin': origin,
    'referer': referer,
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/102.0.1245.33',
}

json_data = {
    'id': 22,
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
    'method': 'call',
    'params': {
        'args': [],
        'model': 'report.pos.order',
        'method': 'read_group',
        'kwargs': {
            'context': {
                'pivot_column_groupby': [
                    'date:month',
                ],
                'pivot_row_groupby': [
                    'product_id',
                ],
            },
            'domain': [],
            'fields': [
                'product_qty:sum',
                'average_price:avg',
                'price_total:sum',
            ],
            'groupby': [
                'product_id',
            ],
            'lazy': False,
        },
    },
}


def get_csrf():
    #get csrf_token
    r = s.get('https://www.odoo.com/web/login')
    soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
    g = soup.head.script.text
    g = g.split('\"')
    csrf_token = g[1]
    return csrf_token


with requests.Session() as s:
    csrf_token = get_csrf()
    data = {
        'csrf_token': csrf_token,
        'login': login,
        'password': password,
        'redirect': ''
    }
    r = s.post('https://www.odoo.com/web/login', headers=headers, data=data)
    re = s.post(api_url, cookies=r.cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
    print (re.json())
```

I suspected that my script wasnt giving me a 'good' session_id to scrape the api. So i wrote another script(below) using playwright module

```
from cred import password, login
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False)
    baseurl = "https://www.odoo.com/web/login"
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(baseurl)
    cookie = context.cookies()
    print(cookie) #show me what cookies you have
    page.fill('#login', login)
    page.fill('#password', password)
    page.click("button[type='submit']")
    time.sleep(2000.2) #just to give me time to check what the session_id is on the network tab
    browser.close()
```

to print my session_ id and gave it some sleep time so i can go into the element tab of webkit and compare what was printed in my terminal as my cookie value to what the browser showed. They were different.

If i use the cookie from the element tab of webkit in the original script it works while the one from thw terminal dosent. Why is that? and how can i get it to work programatically?

Comment: usually session_id is valid only few minuts - for security reason.

Comment: Please add you whole code, when you try to get session_id and what do you do next with it, how do you set it, post request to API....

Comment: @MeT ive made necessary edits

Comment: @furas dont cookies last for a few months at least?

Comment: you can set cookies even for years but cookie with session ID usually is set for few minutes - for security reason. Hacker could catch your cookie with session ID and access your account. And portals on every new request may set new value in sesssion ID to stop hackers to access your account.

Comment: but the first code in my question still works and its the same session_id from 3 days ago

Comment: @Tony you didn't post api_url i can't reproduce it.

Comment: the problem is the info is sensitive so even if i share the url you wont be able to use without the session_id which would basically be like sharing login details right? i was hoping it was a simple answer since im new to web scraping